# Swift autolayout : constraints in sub-view not working

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I am trying to set up a view with two collection views and a view on the center , which in turn has elements inside it.

I have been trying to set constraints using visual format like this :

```
func setupViews() {

    self.view.addSubview(playGroundView)
    self.view.addSubview(firstCollectionView)
    self.view.addSubview(secondCollectionView)

    self.playGroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear


    aTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    titleTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    searchBar?.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray


    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        playGroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        firstCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        secondCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }

    self.playGroundView.addSubview(publishButton)
    self.playGroundView.addSubview(searchBar!)
    self.playGroundView.addSubview(aTextView)
    self.playGroundView.addSubview(titleTextView)

    publishButton.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: publishButton, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 44))
    aTextView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: aTextView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 44))
    titleTextView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: titleTextView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 44))
    searchBar!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: searchBar!, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 44))

    self.playGroundView.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0]-2-|", views: publishButton)
    self.playGroundView.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:[v0]-2-|", views: publishButton)
    self.playGroundView.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|-2-[v0(44)]", views: searchBar!)


    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: aTextView)

    self.playGroundView.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.playGroundView.layoutSubviews()

    self.view.addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-8-[v0(100)][v1][v2(100)]-8-|", views: secondCollectionView,playGroundView,firstCollectionView)

    self.view.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0]-2-|", views: playGroundView)
    self.view.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0]-2-|", views: secondCollectionView)
    self.view.addConstraintsWithFormat("V:[v0]-2-|", views: firstCollectionView)



    if(self.isCreate){
        self.titleTextView.text = self.recipeDictionary?.value(forKey: "recipeName") as! String!
    }
}


// Function to set constraints

 func addConstraintsWithFormat(_ format: String, views: UIView...) {

        var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()
        for (index,view) in views.enumerated() {
            let key = "v\(index)"
            viewsDictionary[key] = view
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    }
```

I don't see the elements inside the sub-view (playGroundView) being rendered. Can someone please suggest what am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try the following to debug:

1. Temporarily set a solid background color to playGroundView instead of `UIColor.clear` and run it to make playGroundView is having a correct size and position.
2. Temporarily set borders to the missing subviews and run it to see if the views are even within the playGroundView bounds. Alternatively, you can also run the code, go to Xcode > Debug > View Debugging > Capture View Hierarchy
3. Set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false for `publishButton`, `searchBar`, etc before adding to playGroundView. While it is not wrong to perform that in your helper function `addConstraintsWithFormat`, there is no need to make that call multiple times.

Comment: I did try setting the background color of the playground view. The frame of the view is as I expect it to be. The contained view elements are not being shown , I have tried setting a background for them as well, as you can see in the code.

Comment: You can also try to add constraints to playGroundView instead of setting them on the subview directly. For example `self.playGroundView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: publishButton, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 44))`

Comment: I am suspecting the subviews' frames are zero, hence even background color is not showing.

Comment: Thanks , I will try it out.

Comment: Tried it, no luck. PlayGroundView is of type UIScrollView.

Comment: Have you fixed it yet? If you haven't, you might want to try to temporarily change playGroundView to become an UIView instance. If the subviews show up correctly when playGroundView is an UIView instance instead of UIScrollView, it might hint that the problem has something to do with UIScrollView.

Comment: Yes I did fix it. The height on one of the element was missing. You pointing out towards View Debugging helped me. Thank you!